# Is the term exogenous in OLS a misnomer?

Tags: least-squares, terminology, endogeneity

in a simple linear regression model 
$$y=\beta _1 + \beta _2 x + \epsilon$$

**We define $x$ to be exogenous if** 
$$E(\epsilon|x)=0$$

I am a bit puzzled as to why this term is called "exogenous", which I intuitively understand to mean something like "not causally influenced by the other variables in the model, including $\epsilon$, since it clearly does not mean that $\epsilon$ and $x$ are independent. We can have for example, that the variance of $\epsilon$ is a function of $x$, or that $\epsilon$ has a t-distribution with $x$ degrees of freedom, or something weird like that.

**So what is the intuitive reason that $x$ is called exogenous if that condition applies, rather than independence?**

Answer (score 2):

You are right, and you are touching  the achilles heel of most econometrics textbooks: the conflation of causal and statistical concepts. $E[\epsilon|x] = 0$ , by itself, formally is just [*mean independence*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205894/how-is-mean-independence-defined). And in fact, *any regression error will be mean independent of the covariates*. That is, any variable $Y$ can be decomposed as $Y = E[Y|X] + \epsilon$ where $E[\epsilon|X] =0$.

Thus, the concept of exogeneity has to go beyond associational ideas, such as mean independence --- it makes sense in a structural framework, where the parameters you want to estimate mean something more than merely a description of the observed distribution. And your intuition about the causal content is on the right track.

The general definition of exogeneity of $X$ is that $X$ is independent of  all other unobserved factors that causes $Y$ except those mediated by $X$ itself -- $\epsilon$ is just a shortcut to represent all those unmodeled factors. In a linear structural equation setting, however, this is usually relaxed to claiming only that the mean of $\epsilon$ is independent of $X$, which is weaker but enough to identify the structural coefficient $\beta$ in that setting.

Comment: The assumption/definition $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon|x)=0$ is on the random variables $\epsilon$ and $x$, not residuals $\hat\varepsilon$ and sample values of $x$. Conflation of the two might confuse the readers.

Comment: @RichardHardy I’m not talking about samples, we can always define the random variable $\epsilon := y - E[y|x]$, with the population values (not sample values), and $\epsilon$ will always be mean independent of $x$. That’s why for that assumption to be meaningful it needs to make reference to something beyond the observed joint probability distribution, such as $\epsilon := y- E[y|do(x)]$.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. What I am trying to say is that residuals are sample realizations of errors/disturbances/innovations/shocks/..., so it makes sense to talk about depence between $\epsilon$ and $x$ but not $\hat\epsilon$ and $x$. Hence, I have a problem understanding what exactly you mean by *any regression residual will be mean independent of the covariates*. Other than that I find your points enlightening.

Comment: @RichardHardy ok, I will change it to regression error instead of residual to make it clear it is a population quantity!